# How to fetch data of an object when im getting the parent object (ex. process have actions, im fetching process) DOCTRINE

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Let's say I have a class named Process, that has name, data.. etc. Then, this process class has a subclass called actions that have: [name, year, data]. So when I want to take all processes I just want to fetch the actions which have the year set in 2020 instead of getting all the actions with all the years.

Is there any way to do this in doctrine?

Something like *SELECT PROCESS WHERE PROCESS.ACTIONS.YEAR LIKE 2020* (but in doctrine)

Sorry for the bad explanation, I hope you can understand it.

ps. I'm trying to print all processes in one twig file but I just want the latest actions.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*IF* you have the relations defined correctly, you can do:

```
SELECT process 
FROM App\Entity\Process process 
LEFT JOIN process.actions action 
WHERE action.year = 2020
```

or in the process repository

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('process')
    ->leftJoin('process.actions', 'action')
    ->where('action.year = 2020')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

not certain if you get duplicates, though. In the DQL-Query you can probably just say `SELECT DISTINCT process` etc. And I'd guess in the query builder variant, you might have to add `->select('DISTINCT process')` before the `getQuery`.

Comment: It is working, but only when I use query as itself, i mean, without using the doctrine methods like where leftjoin etc. Thankss!